# How to insert Label values into MS Access Table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, ms-access, label

Hi i want to basically insert the values in the labels to a table in ms access.
I have done it for textbox and it stores but for Label When i try to store it no error shows up but it does not store in the database what should i do? I am using the following code

```
static OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\New folder\Project 1.0\WebSite1\New Microsoft Office Access 2007 Database.accdb");
    OleDbDataAdapter ada = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbDataReader dr;


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string str = "insert into Orders (Products, Amount)" + " values (@p1, @p2)";
            con.Open();
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(str, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Label18.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", Label16.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception Occured");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con != null && con.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            { con.Close(); }
        }
    }
```

Also i tried storing textbox value into the same Table "Orders" under the column "Address" but facing the same above issue...The table does not update. I have used this code before for other textboxes etc for different tables and it has worked fine..

```
static OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\New folder\Project 1.0\WebSite1\New Microsoft Office Access 2007 Database.accdb");
    OleDbDataAdapter ada = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbDataReader dr;

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        {
            string str = "insert into Orders (Address)" + " values (@p1)";
            con.Open();
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(str, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", TextBox1.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code seems correct. Could you step into with a debugger and check what is the text of the two labels?

Comment: The text of label18 = Ashirwad Atta 1KG, Label16 = 32

Comment: @user2211486 what is the data type of Amount column in database?

Comment: Number. I changed it from text to number for the Amount column

Answer (score 0):

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement

try with

```
   string str = "insert into Orders (Products, Amount) values (?,?)";
```

You can change the code as below

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\New folder\Project 1.0\WebSite1\New Microsoft Office Access 2007 Database.accdb"))
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into Orders (Products, Amount) values (?,?)", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Label18.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", int.Parse(Label16.Text));
            con.Open();
            int no = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Console.WriteLine("number of rows affected = " + no);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception Occured :" ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried it, no error but the changes don't reflect in the database :(

Comment: Type or namespace not found for sqlConnection and SqlCommand :(

Comment: Invlaid token "using" in class, Label16/18 is a field but is used like a type....

Comment: @user2211486 problem may be due to type of Amount field, you can try with `int.Parse(Label16.Text)` or `Decimal.Parse(Label16.Text)`

Comment: have you try with `int.Parse(Label16.Text)` as well?

Comment: Tried that too still its not updating the table. Its not just the amount column, it doesn't even update the Product and Address column. The odd part is that i have used this same code for other textbox controls on a different page on a different table and it works fine there. And now if not the label but the testbox should work but even thats not happening.

Comment: long shot but isn't the label text stored in the Caption property?